# How to have two labels on the y-axis and one label on the x-axis?

Tags: python, plot, axis-labels, twinx

I am trying to make a Python plot with labels on both the right and left sides on the vertical axis. However, I cannot manage to get a label on the bottom of the horizontal axis. Can anyone help me, please?

I have made this code, and it works fine, except I can't find a way to get an x-label:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, y1 = plt.subplots()
y2 = y1.twinx()

x = np.linspace(0,10,10)

f1 = x*2
plt.plot(x,f1)
f2 = x*3
plt.plot(x,f2)
f3 = x*4
plt.plot(x,f3)

y1.set_ylabel('y1')
y2.set_ylabel('y2')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QwLL.jpg)

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-axis-labels-to-a-plot-in-matplotlib-in-python `plt.xlabel("Horizonal label")`

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it doesn't work